# Fastest way to filter object by multiple properties

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have an array of objects that I want to filter for a string. So I want to check multiple properties if they contain the filter string (case insensitive).

Here's the array:

```
[{
  id: "01234", 
  name: "My Object 01234", 
  short_name: "MO01234"
}, ...]
```

So all of the following filter strings should match that object: `0123`, `obj`, `mO01` etc.

Here's what I have right now:

```
const filterString = this.filterString.toLowerCase();
return myObjects.filter(
  entry => {
    return 
      entry.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterString) >= 0 || 
      entry.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterString) >= 0 ||    
      entry.short_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterString) >= 0;
  }
);
```

Can you think of a faster/cleaner way to do that?

Comment: Please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can do it faster, but cleaner may be something like that

```
const filterString = this.filterString.toLowerCase();
return myObjects.filter((entry) => {
    return Object.values(entry).some((value) => {
        return value.toLowerCase().includes(filterString)
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to put additional properties in your object, perhaps you could concatenate `id`, `name` and `short_name` (already in lowercase) into a single string and store it in the object as e.g. `search_key`; then you'd only have to check that.

```
{
  id: "01234", 
  name: "My Object 01234", 
  short_name: "MO01234",
  search_key: "01234:my object 01234:mo01234"
}

return myObjects.filter(
  entry => entry.search_key.indexOf(filterString) >= 0
);
```

One thing you have to be mindful of in this case is to prevent unintended matches that may arise because e.g. the last few characters of `id` and the first few characters of `name` together produce a match. This is why I used a `:` delimiter here, assuming that's a character that can't appear in an ID or a short name.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let objects = [{
    id: "01234", 
    name: "My Object 01234", 
    short_name: "MO01234"
},
{
    id: "test", 
    name: "test", 
    short_name: "test"
}];

const filter = (collection, searchFor) => {
    return collection.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).reduce((a,b) => a || String(b).toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFor.toLowerCase()) > -1, false))
}

console.log(filter(objects, "0123"));
console.log(filter(objects, "obj"));
console.log(filter(objects, "mO01"));
```

You could also extend this function to take a set of columns as parameter to filter on.

Another version using Regex:

```
const filterRegex = (collection, searchFor) => {
    return collection.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).reduce((a,b) => a || String(b).match(new RegExp(searchFor, 'gi')), false))
}


console.log(filterRegex(objects, "0123"));
console.log(filterRegex(objects, "obj"));
console.log(filterRegex(objects, "mO01"));
```